# Community page is not loading in the community builder

Tags: community, community-builder, partner-communities, lightning-community

EDIT:
 [image]
looked at the developer console and this is what I see:

> Refused to display
>   'https://xxxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fsfsites%2Fl…OP%26siteId%3D0DM41000000GHYK%26language%3Den_US%26orgId%3D00D41000000W5Rn'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
>
> https://xxxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fsfsites%2Fl…OP%26siteId%3D0DM41000000GHYK%26language%3Den_US%26orgId%3D00D41000000W5Rn
>   net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Community page is not loading in the community builder I have no idea what is going on and I have been waiting waiting no response its been 10 minutes

I found that its known issue? is that fixed? this post is 10 days old
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008esnAAA

Comment: Have you set required authorization for the landing page?. thats what the link says and also it says issue is in review which means its not fixed yet. They have given a work around in that link did you try that

Comment: i did not quite get how to do required authorization for the landing page in community builder because the menu is not loading and if i go to the site.com I don't see, do you happen to know how to set the authorization?

Comment: by any chance do you have any helpful info from the browser dev console or network tab?

Comment: updated my question with more info

Answer (score 1):

I'm replaying in order to share my experience with the same issue.

I had similar problem with community builder, which failed to load. This happened also after that the known issue was fixed.

My problem was connected to cache and cookies, i on suggestion of salesforce support, deleted all the cache and cookies related to salesforce, and now the Community Builder load properly.

I hope that it can be useful to other people that may experience same problem.